# PDF Downloading not functioning properly

Tags: php, download

I am using the following code to download a PDF....

```
   header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="NewName.pdf"');
   readfile($root_path.'/full-tile-book.pdf');
```

It's a 13 MB file and only downloads like 130k and of course can't be opened.  How do I debug what the issue is here?  My path to the pdf is correct.

Comment: open result in notepad, maybe you'll notice a php error in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are running into a memory/filesize error?  I've had problems in the past dumping large files with readfile.  In addition to setting the Content-Length header, I recommend using [`fpassthru()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php), as it does not read the file into a buffer, it just dumps it.

```
set_time_limit(0); // disable timeout
$file = $root_path.'/full-tile-book.pdf';
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="NewName.pdf"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
session_write_close(); // remove this line if sessions are not active
$f = fopen($file, 'rb');
fpassthru($f);
fclose($f);
exit;
```

EDIT: If you are using any sessions_code, it is a good idea to end the session before starting the file dump process.  I have updated my example to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a few items. Assign the filename to $file, then try:

```
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

This will ensure that the client is expecting the correct length, and the output buffer flushes nicely in between.

Answer (score 0):

see downloaded file perhaps have bad address use in PHP.
You can follow this tutorial for file download in PHP.

> HTML headers must be sent before any
>   output is sent to the browser. PHP
>   uses the header function to pass raw
>   HTML headers. For this example we're
>   going to get the filename from the URL
>   www.yourdomain.com/download.php?file=download.zip.

```
<? 
$dir="/path/to/file/";
if (isset($_REQUEST["file"])) {
    $file=$dir.$_REQUEST["file"];
    header("Content-type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-length: ".filesize($file));
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename="".basename($file).""");
    readfile("$file");
} else {
    echo "No file selected";
}
 ?>
```

> We started with setting the directory
>   where the files to be downloaded are
>   located in $dir. Be sure not to use in
>   $dir. Then we checked to make sure a
>   filename was specified in the request.
>   If a file was specified then we set
>   $file to the path to the file and the
>   filename. Now that the prep work is
>   done its time to send the file to the
>   browser.
>
> The first header statement tells the
>   browser to expect a download. The next
>   two header statements tell the browser
>   the format of the data and the size of
>   the file respectively. The last header
>   statement tells the browser the name
>   of the file. Finally the readfile
>   statement sends the file to the
>   browser.

[More information.](http://www.higherpass.com/php/Tutorials/File-Download-Security/)