# PDF file not correctly encoded when downloading a pdf file from php

Tags: php, pdf

This might be a duplicate but I have searched for the solution for so long and I still could not solve my problem. I have a localhost server where it stored some pdf files for download.

I implemented the following function to force the download:

```
if(isset($_POST['dlPDF']))
{

$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/Upload/'.$pdfName;

    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$pdfName");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    // read the file from disk
    readfile($file);
}
```

However I could not open the pdf file properly since it says "the pdf file is not correctly encoded".
FYI, the downloaded pdf file is always a few Kb larger than the original file.

Please kindly let me know if there is anything I can do to make the pdf readable and I appreciate your help.

Comment: This solution helped me a lot
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955034/pdf-downloading-not-functioning-properly